# PHP simple login script, not displaying error

Tags: php, html, forms, if-statement, echo

The `$error` shows up all of the time and not when an error is found in the script. I set the `else` to `showForm` which then is meant to show the code on `$error` in the `<?php echo $error; ?>` box.

Thanks for your help in advance and I hope to find the answer to the question soon.

```
<?php

$Password = 'password'; // Password here

   if (isset($_POST['submit_pwd'])){
      $pass = isset($_POST['pass']) ? $_POST['pass'] : '';

      if ($pass != $Password) {
         showForm("Wrong password");
         exit();     
      }
   } else {
      showForm();
      exit();
   }

function showForm($error="Error, please try again."){
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
HEAD CONTENT HERE
</head>
<body>
  <section class="container">
    <div class="login">
      <h1>Login Area</h1>
      <br />
      <div class="error">
        <h2><?php echo $error; ?></h2>  
      </div>
      <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" name="pwd">
        <p><input type="password" name="pass" value="" placeholder="Password"></p>
        <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit_pwd" value="Login"></p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
</html>

<?php   
}
?>
```

Comment: It is really odd coding practice to have a function which does nothing but basically produce an HTML document.  Why not use an include here.  If have a file like 'login_form.php' and then just do `include 'login_form.php' instead of making a function call?

Comment: Mike, the above code is the login form and i'm using require_once('protect.php') on the pages that i'm protecting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a default error value.. so when you first load the page, $_POST is not set. The $error value going into the function should initially be blank and ONLY set if there is an error. Also, I would add the h2 tags to the function call. That way, when there is no error, the empty h2's won't take up any space.

```
<?php

$Password = 'test'; // Password here

   if (isset($_POST['submit_pwd'])){
      $pass = isset($_POST['pass']) ? $_POST['pass'] : '';

      if ($pass != $Password) {
         showForm("<h2>Wrong password</h2>");
         exit();     
      }
   } else {
      showForm();
      exit();
   }

function showForm($error=""){
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
HEAD CONTENT HERE
</head>
<body>
  <section class="container">
    <div class="login">
      <h1>Login Area</h1>
      <br />
      <div class="error">
        <?php echo $error; ?> 
      </div>
      <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" name="pwd">
        <p><input type="password" name="pass" value="" placeholder="Password"></p>
        <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit_pwd" value="Login"></p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
</html>

<?php   
}

?>
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.. don't forget to accept the answer if it did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

As mjayt explained in his answer, your `showForm()` function will always output the error message.

When there is no error, do not call the `showForm()` function.

Therefore, change the code to:

```
   if (isset($_POST['submit_pwd'])){
      $pass = isset($_POST['pass']) ? $_POST['pass'] : '';

      if ($pass != $Password) {
         showForm("Wrong password");
         exit();     
      }
   }
```

In other words, there is no need for the `else` condition.  Alternatively, you could leave the else code block there, but do nothing in it.

The `exit()` command is not required since it is the last thing you code is doing. It will stop after that anyway. If, however, you add additional PHP code later on, you may need the exit() if you do not want that code processed.